# Case Statement Not Working for me

Tags: excel, vb.net, switch-statement, case

I'm having trouble understanding what is going wrong with my case statement below...

```
Select Case aFunction.getListOfWords.Intersect(aUTL.getListOfWords).Count

    Case aFunction.getListOfWords.Intersect(aUTL.getListOfWords).Count > 7
        protoWorksheet.Cells(rowCounter, 12) = "X"
    Case aFunction.getListOfWords.Intersect(aUTL.getListOfWords).Count = 7
        protoWorksheet.Cells(rowCounter, 11) = "X"
    Case aFunction.getListOfWords.Intersect(aUTL.getListOfWords).Count = 6
        protoWorksheet.Cells(rowCounter, 10) = "X"
    Case aFunction.getListOfWords.Intersect(aUTL.getListOfWords).Count = 5 Or 4
        protoWorksheet.Cells(rowCounter, 9) = "X"
    Case aFunction.getListOfWords.Intersect(aUTL.getListOfWords).Count = 3
        protoWorksheet.Cells(rowCounter, 8) = "X"
End Select
```

The only successful case it goes into is `5 or 4` but only for the `4`. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `aFunction.getListOfWords.Intersect(aUTL.getListOfWords).Count` from each case line.  The `Select Case` sets the value to be tested and the `Case` lines just need the expected output.

Also when using `OR` just list the values comma separated.

```
Select Case aFunction.getListOfWords.Intersect(aUTL.getListOfWords).Count

    Case  > 7
        protoWorksheet.Cells(rowCounter, 12) = "X"
    Case  7
        protoWorksheet.Cells(rowCounter, 11) = "X"
    Case  6
        protoWorksheet.Cells(rowCounter, 10) = "X"
    Case  5, 4
        protoWorksheet.Cells(rowCounter, 9) = "X"
    Case  3
        protoWorksheet.Cells(rowCounter, 8) = "X"
End Select
```

Comment: Ahhh ok awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @Bob - Note you can (should?) add a `Case Else` part to have a catchall if the value is say `2`, `1`, or anything else not already accounted for.